# PHP simple calendar with attendance system

Tags: php, html, dreamweaver, simple-form, time-and-attendance

I'm designing a simple attendance system with calendar using `dreamweaver`, `xampp`.

I already have the user/admin login page and also the registration page.
What I'm trying to do now is how can I make the days on this simple calendar clickable?

I mean when I click the day, for example, day 1 of january 2016, it will redirect me to another page which is the attendance system (that I'm currently doing).

Here's the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Attendance</title>

</head>
<body>
<?php
/* Set the default timezone */
date_default_timezone_set("America/Montreal");

/* Set the date */
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

$day = date('d', $date);
$month = date('m', $date);
$year = date('Y', $date);
$firstDay = mktime(0,0,0,$month, 1, $year);
$title = strftime('%B', $firstDay);
$dayOfWeek = date('D', $firstDay);
$daysInMonth = cal_days_in_month(0, $month, $year);
/* Get the name of the week days */
$timestamp = strtotime('next Sunday');
$weekDays = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $weekDays[] = strftime('%a', $timestamp);
    $timestamp = strtotime('+1 day', $timestamp);
}
$blank = date('w', strtotime("{$year}-{$month}-01"));
?>
<table class='table table-bordered' style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="7" class="text-center"> <?php echo $title ?> <?php echo $year ?> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($weekDays as $key => $weekDay) : ?>
            <td class="text-center"><?php echo $weekDay ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php for($i = 0; $i < $blank; $i++): ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++): ?>
            <?php if($day == $i): ?>
                <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
            <?php else: ?>
                <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if(($i + $blank) % 7 == 0): ?>
                </tr><tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endfor; ?>
        <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $blank + $daysInMonth) % 7 != 0; $i++): ?>
            <td></td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Credits to the one who could do this simple calendar on PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php for($i = 0; $i < $blank; $i++): ?>
        <td></td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= $daysInMonth; $i++): ?>
        <?php if($day == $i): ?>
            <td><strong><?php echo $i ?></strong></td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td><?php echo '<a href="attendance?date='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>'?></td> //edited line
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(($i + $blank) % 7 == 0): ?>
            </tr><tr>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <?php for($i = 0; ($i + $blank + $daysInMonth) % 7 != 0; $i++): ?>
        <td></td>
    <?php endfor; ?>
```